# Drawing a profile (bar) chart with d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a profile chart with d3. My data contains a panel of about 70 measures ranging from 3.5 to 10 and a label for each bar. I would like to draw a chart so that values greater than 6 are drawn upward and below 6 downward. Values greater than 6.5 becomes green bars, below 5.5 turn to red. Below is the aimed chart.
[image]

Using the follow d3 code, I managed to draw the graph below - struggled a bit being new to d3.
[image]

There are several issues still, for which I'm ask some help:
1. green bars are to high, I would like to use a fixed range from 3 to 12, the higher green bar in the graph has a value of 7.3 and however reaches the top (10px margin).
2. I'm not able to display the y-axis values, I'd like 3, 6 and 9 to be displayed.
3. x and y-axis are too thick, I'd prefer 1px.
4. some bars in the panel may have no value, I'd like those to be displayed as empty bars.

Starting from the code below, what should I do? Where did I go wrong with axis display. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function draw(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.value = d.value - 6.0;
        });

var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 80, left: 50 },
    padding = { top: 2, right: 2, bottom: 2, left: 2 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right - padding.left - padding.right,
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom - padding.top - padding.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - padding.top - padding.bottom, 0])
    .domain([-3, 6]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(function(d) { return d.label; });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(yScale([3,6,9]));

xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+padding.top+"," + (height-padding.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-50)" );

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+padding.left+", "+padding.top+")")
    .call(yAxis)

svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.label); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d3.max([0, d.value])); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(yScale(d.value)-yScale(0)); })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
           if(d.value < -0.5) { return "red"; }
           else if (d.value > 0.5) { return "green"; }
           else { return "lightgray"; }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the great help of Mark, I was able to achieve my goal, the corrected code is below with comments on modifications.
[image]

D3 code:

```
function draw(data) {

// padding was removed
// data is no more shifted by 6, graph is centered on 6 instead.
var margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 20 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

// removed extend on scaling which forced bars to span on the whole height 
// since original data is scaled from 4 to 10, I'd like the bar reflect absolute values
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([3, 10]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(function(d) {
           return d.cell;
           });

// tickValues have been added to force proper ticks on y-axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .tickValues([3, 6, 9]);

xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
                       return d.cell;
                       }));

// transform attribute was added to shift the whole graph by margin.left
// this explains why the y-axis and ticks were not visible
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-50)" );

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("-log(GI50) uM");

// y-scale is now centered on 6, greater draws upward, lesser draws downward 
// color is set using a CSS with [5, 7] range set to gray
svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      if (d.value < 5) { return "bar negative"; }
      else if (d.value > 7) { return "bar positive"; }
      else { return "bar neutral"; }
      })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.cell); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d3.max([6, d.value])); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(yScale(d.value)-yScale(6)); });
}
```

CSS used:

```
.bar.positive { 
    fill: #1a9641; 
}

.bar.negative { 
    fill: #d7191c; 
}

.bar.neutral { 
    fill: #d5d5d5; 
}

.axis text { 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.axis path {
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}

.axis line {
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.chart {
    padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 960px;
    height: 240px;
}
```

Some data:

```
[ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "BT-549",
"value" : 5.846
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "HS 578T",
"value" : 5.429
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "MCF7",
"value" : 5.953
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "MDA-MB-231/ATCC",
"value" : 5.669
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "MDA-MB-435",
"value" : 5.804
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "MDA-N",
"value" : 5.828
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "NCI/ADR-RES",
"value" : 5.575
} ], [ {
"panel" : "BRE",
"cell" : "T-47D",
"value" : 5.959
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "SF-268",
"value" : 5.556
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "SF-295",
"value" : 5.14
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "SF-539",
"value" : 5.431
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "SNB-19",
"value" : 4.884
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "SNB-75",
"value" : 5.465
} ], [ {
"panel" : "CNS",
"cell" : "U251",
"value" : 5.317
} ]
```

Next step will be to add error bars and scale appropriately, add light gray horizontal bars at 5, 7 and 9 and display the tagged bar groups on top of the graph, with appropriate colors, as well as the active compound structure on the side and on demand display or hide axes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused by your code.

1.) you state you want a defined domain of `[3, 12]` but in your yScale you first set it to `domain([-3, 6]);` and then later reset it to min/max using `d3.extent`.  Why?

2.) What's the purpose of `d.value = d.value - 6.0;`, wouldn't you be better served to leave your data alone and then do the comparison's for color around 6.  Instead of trying to map it to 0 and compare around that?

3.) You can configure the axis appearance through CSS.  For what you want use:

```
.axis path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

4.) You can't see your y-axis tick because you've only allocated 2px to them through `left.padding`:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + ", " + padding.top + ")")
```

In fact, I can't figure out your interplay of padding and margins.  The [classic bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) just uses margins, I'd simplify and just use that example.

Putting this all together, here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e4Hcs3bB7G4A64IVH7B0?p=preview).

[image]

Comment: Indeed, 3, 12 is the original range, and -3, 6 the shit data to center on 6. I didn't know about extent, this must be one of the issues. Thanks. Point 2, -6 ahas set to make sure that value below 6 goes down. Indeed, if I could let the data as is, that'd be preferable, I guess I tried to many things before asking. The idea of padding was to make sure that bars stop 2px before axes... purely aesthetic. I didn't really managed to get what I was expecting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the above code and data, I'm trying to draw upper color bar with group tags (BRE, CNS, etc.). I managed to draw two different bars (see pictures) changing the code as follow:

```
nodeEnter
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return lScale(d.cell); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", lScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("style", function(d) { return "fill:"+color(d.panel); });
```

[image]

```
// create a specific scaling function for the x-axis with a reduced spacing between bars
var lScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 1e-6);

nodeEnter
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return lScale(d.cell); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", lScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("style", function(d) { return "fill:"+color(d.panel); });
```

I'd like to create a bar without white spaces between bars of the same color and a separation between groups (different color) and add the group name (d.panel) in the center of the bar.
I thought about creating a map for groups computing min and max on x from the original data.

How can I extract min and max of xScale(d.cell) for each d.panel? Should I loop through the array, or is there a way to use the range of d.panel to group data from xScale(d.cell) to compute the stats?

[image]